# Recursive function that takes two matrices of same size and outputs whether are not they are equal

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function which takes 2 matrices of equal size and returns 1 if they are equal and 0 elsewise.

```
int equal(int[][3], int[][3], int, int);
int main()
{
    int matrixOne[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 9 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };
    int matrixTwo[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 9 }, { 3, 3, 3} };
    cout << equal(matrixOne, matrixTwo, 2, 2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int equal(int matrixOne[][3], int matrixTwo[][3], int row, int column)
{
    if (row < 0)
        return 1;
    if (column < 0)
    {
        column = row;
        row--;
    }
    if (matrixOne[row][column] == matrixTwo[row][column])
        return equal(matrixOne, matrixTwo, row, column - 1);
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work as it should because once column count reaches zero, we have to reset it to the original max column count, it can be done the first time by making column=row; but afterwards it just doesn't traverse through all of the matrix.

Is it even possible to solve this question using this function prototype?

Comment: Out of interest, what's so wrong with a solution based on memcmp?

Comment: @Bathsheba Using recursion is question requirement.

Comment: Oops. My answer was incorrect.

Comment: `column = row;` shouldn't it be `column = 2;`?

Comment: @kiner_shah `column = 2;` fixes it but the code won't work for matrices of other sizes.

Comment: But your function itself isn't generic. `int matrixTwo[][3]`. It shouldn't be `3` in the second dimension then.

Comment: Out of interest, why `int equal`, `0` and `1` and not `bool equal`, `true` and `false` (and not `bool operator == (Matrix, Matrix)`)?

Answer (score 0):

You function will work, but there are some changes I had to do:

1. Replacing `column = row` with `column = 2`. Note that in the function parameters in the provided code the matrices were declared as `matrixOne[][3]`. Since `3` is in the second dimension, I had to assign `2` to column. To make the function generic, you will have to change your code.
2. Placing the check for `row < 0` after column check. You can figure out the reason for this after some debugging; if this is not done, the recursion will not stop at the expected point.

Here is the modified code:

```
int equal(int[][3], int[][3], int, int);
int main()
{
    int matrixOne[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 9 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };
    int matrixTwo[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 9 }, { 3, 3, 3} };
    cout << equal(matrixOne, matrixTwo, 2, 2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int equal(int matrixOne[][3], int matrixTwo[][3], int row, int column)
{
    if (column < 0)
    {
        column = 2;
        row--;
    }
    if (row < 0)
        return 1;
    if (matrixOne[row][column] == matrixTwo[row][column])
        return equal(matrixOne, matrixTwo, row, column - 1);
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the link where I tested the code: https://ideone.com/4tBpJg

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a generic version that allows matrices with any number of dimensions of any size of any type. You can make the size of the array a template parameter so that you don't have to pass it in.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<T>::value, bool>::type
equal(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // T is not an array, (a is a single dimension array)
        // so just compare the values.
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value, bool>::type
equal(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // T is an array (So a is a multidimensional array)
        // recursively call the "equal" function on the
        // lower dimensional arrays.
        if (!equal(a[i], b[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Modified the size so you can see it better
    int matrixOne[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 9 } };
    int matrixTwo[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 9 } };

    /*
    equal(matrixOne, matrixTwo)
    // bool equal<int[3], 2> equal(int[3][2], int[3][2]);
        is equivalent to:
    equal(matrixOne[0], matrixTwo[0]) && equal(matrixOne[1], matrixTwo[1])
    // bool equal<int, 3> equal(int[3], int[3]);
        And they just compare the 3 values per column
    */

    // prints 1
    std::cout << equal(matrixOne, matrixTwo) << '\n';
}
```

But, since the functions are just a multidimensional array of "int"s, you can just [`std::memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>

// Change the above to
template<class T, std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_array<T>::value && !std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, bool
>::type
equal(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]);

template<class T, std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_array<T>::value && !std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, bool
>::type
equal(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]);

// And the new one for trivial types
template<class T, std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, bool>::type
equal(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept {
    return std::memcmp(a, b, sizeof(a)) == 0;
}
```